# NextJS Rewrites TypeError: (0 , _resolveRewrites.default) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, next.js

I got an Error when using Rewrites in NextJS by using references in NextJS Documentation
I tried to reinstall node_modules but it still not working
Enviroment Variables is working, but rewrites feature is not working

This is my next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    APPNAME: 'NextJS Exercise!!!',
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/login',
        destination: '/auth/login',
      }, 
    ]
  },
}
```

This is the error what i got
TypeError: (0 , _resolveRewrites.default) is not a function

[Next.config.js Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DRg7.png)
[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMQSr.png)

Comment: Does deleting the .next folder and reruning work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I encountered this problem before with a clean nextjs project.

There is a quick fix:

- Remove the node_modules
- Remove package-lock.json
- `npm install` again.

If the above cannot help, please try to upgrade the nextjs package to `10.2.0`,
`npm install next@latest`

Comment: ahh i see, it works like a charm,  i was tried to remove node_modules then npm install before, but not work, it works when remove node_modules and package-lock.json then npm install

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the solution from @Mic doesn't work unfortunately for me, but when I clean the cache first it works so run this in order

Then if you are using yarn:

`yarn cache clean`

`rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock && yarn install`

Or if you are using npm:

`npm cache clean`

`rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install`

Answer (score 0):

If the quick fix from @MicFung doesn't work try using `yarn`.

- Remove the node_modules
- Remove package-lock.json **and / or** Remove yarn.lock
- yarn install

Answer (score 0):

Another fix could be to remove the .next map in the root of your project and rerun the start script.